# Dev Weblogic can not bind address which is not used

Tags: weblogic

I've encounter a problem that I cannot start up weblogic 11gR1 development server in oepe eclipse after one time I stop the server start up progress before it finish all task in the start up progress.

Here's the error message I got every time I try to start up weblogic 11gR1.

```
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms400m -Xmx512m -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=D:\workspace\ CommonLib\antlr-2.7.6rc1.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1033\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\lib\tools.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.3.0.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1033\profiles\default\native;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\jre\bin;D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\bin;D:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\tools\datadirect;D:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;D:\java\32bit\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8
.
starting weblogic with Java version:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\bin\java -client -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE  -Xms400m -Xmx512m -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Djava.awt.headless=true -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Xverify:none  -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... -Dplatform.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1033\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:20 AM CST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Version 17.0-b17 from Sun Microsystems Inc.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:20 AM CST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.3.0  Fri Apr 9 00:05:28 PDT 2010 1321401 > 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:21 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:21 AM CST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:21 AM CST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:21 AM CST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log00003. Log messages will continue to be logged in D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:21 AM CST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:21 AM CST> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000438> <Unable to load performance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that wlntio.dll is in: 'D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1033\profiles\default\native;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\jre\bin;D:\java\32bit\JDK16~2.0_2\bin;D:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\tools\datadirect;D:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;D:\java\32bit\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8'
> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:22 AM CST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:23 AM CST> <Warning> <Store> <BEA-280101> <The persistent file store "_WLS_AdminServer" is forced to use buffered I/O and so may have significantly degraded performance. Either the OS/hardware environment does not support the chosen write policy or the native wlfileio library is missing. See store open log messages for the requested and final write policies. See the documentation on store synchronous write policy configuration for advice.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\cg.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\cg.log00003. Log messages will continue to be logged in D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\servers\AdminServer\logs\cg.log.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Error> <Server> <BEA-002606> <Unable to create a server socket for listening on channel "Default[3]". The address 127.0.0.1 might be incorrect or another process is using port 7001: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:d750:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "%Host DNS name%", maps to multiple IP addresses: 192.168.215.80, fe80:0:0:0:20da:75b4:f1db:efa3%11> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:20da:75b4:f1db:efa3:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 192.168.215.80:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "cg" running in Development Mode> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
<Jun 19, 2014 10:24:24 AM CST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode> 
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
```

The start up progress was frozed at the 87% of "starting weblogic progress" in eclipse,
then eclipse throw out an error message dialog that server start up failed without any further error message.

You might say that there is a process using port 7001, but this is the first time
I start up dev server in eclipse after restarting my computer, and I've check out port 7001 by netstat cmd before I start my dev server, so I am sure that 7001 is available before I start dev server.

And this is what I got after starting up my weblogic server.
netstat after starting up weblogic dev server in eclipse

http://i57.tinypic.com/2hyk42.png

I don't understand what's wrong is going on my dev environment.
I have re-install my oepe eclipse, weblogic dev server and reset eclipse and weblogic domain, delete any oracle related setting file in my user directory,
but still I can not start up my dev server to test if my project is ok.

My OS is windows 7 without admin privileges, 
eclipse is oepe-helios-all-in-one-11.1.1.6.1.201010012100-win32
with server adapter weblogic 11gR1 patchSet2

Does anyone know what's wrong is going on my enviroment? 
Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your config.xml file for your domain at:

```
D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\cg\config\config.xml
```

Check the following:

```
<listen-port>7001</listen-port>
<listen-address>127.0.0.1</listen-address>
```

You may need to change the `listen-address` to be your actual IP or hostname. You can also change `listen-port` to something else just to see if 7001 is truly the problem.

That said, normally a server will never reach the `RUNNING` state if you have binding problems. Check to see if you can reach the admin console at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/console
```

Comment: I've solve this problem. It's because of issues from eclipse or weblogic, it's about a malware monitor service installed in my system that used the 7001 port.And the odd point is that it can't occupy the whole port in os, so it appears that there are two process using port 7001 when I query netstat.